# mathematical permutation code?

Tags: java, math, permutation

One part of my app has 6 different inputs, where each input has 5 different possible values. This works out to 15,625 permutations. I'd like to believe that I don't have to code out every single one, but I'm really unsure. I've started coding it as if I have to code out every single one, but it got me thinking that there must be a better way. So I've come here to see if any more experienced coders know of a better way to do this.

Is there any other way? Other than having to code out every single permutation?

Equation Explanation: 
There are 6 limbs (inputs). Each input depends on its percentage of leftover health. These dependencies (expressed as a percentage) are less than or equal to 0, greater than 0 and less than or equal to 25, greater than 25 and less than or equal to 50, greater than 50 and less than or equal to 75, and greater than 75. Each permutation will more often than not result in a different output. This output is displayed within the app for the user to use.

[EDITS] This is not a damage calculation. These are penalties applied to player stats based upon how much damage they've taken. The expected results either don't affect their stats or reduce their stats. Occasionally, the number subtracted is the same for different variables. If you look at the code below, you'll see that the number is the same for `head > 0.0 && head <= 0.25` and `chest > 0.0 && chest <= 0.25`, as well as `chest > 0.25 && chest <= 0.50` and `leftarm > 0.25 && leftarm <= 0.50` and `rgitharm > 0.25 && rightarm <= 0.50`

[EDITS] I'll reply to the comments here:

@Frank N. Stein: Oops. Thanks for the correction :)

@aioobe: I've edited the `equation explanation` to hopefully clarify the expected outcomes.

@ian: Those values cannot be worked out as they're percentages. I would never be able to work them out.

@Marco13: It seems that way simply because I haven't finished coding every permutation out yet. On second thought, I don't think I need to display dead. I can just leave those permutations out of the calculations as it's taken care of in a different activity.

@aioobe: Is this better than enumerating the outcomes as suggested by @Ian and @Durandal.

@Danil Gaponov: Is this better or worse than what was suggested by @Durandal in his/her answer?

@Durandal: I've updated the `equation explanation` to hopefully be more clear about what I'm expecting for each of these outcomes.

Thanks for your patience :)

Would I be able to do something similar to this:

```
//  HEALTH
//  N > 0.75            == Full
//  N > 0.50 && <= 0.75 == HighHealth
//  N > 0.25 && <= 0.50 == MedHealth
//  N > 0.00 && <= 0.25 == LowHealth
//  N <= 0.00           == Dead
```

IE I could then write `h == Full` or `h == Health.Full`. This would make my life a lot easier would make the code much easier to read. Although, I'd still have to work out every single permutation, it'd be a little more manageable.

Another idea I have is to put these calculations in a different class and run it within the activity. Something like this:

```
//      SETTING DATA
//      WEAPON 1
//      MELEE
weapon1attack.setText(PenaltiesMeleeHelper);
weapon1accuracy.setText(PenaltiesMeleeHelper);
//      RANGED
weapon1thrownattack.setText(PenaltiesThrownHelper);
weapon1thrownaccuracy.setText(PenaltiesThrownHelper);
//      WEAPON 2
//      MELEE
weapon2attack.setText(PenaltiesMeleeHelper);
weapon2accuracy.setText(PenaltiesMeleeHelper);
//      RANGED
weapon2thrownattack.setText(PenaltiesThrownHelper);
weapon2thrownaccuracy.setText(PenaltiesThrownHelper);
```

Would any of these be possible?

[EDIT] Would an mathematical algorithm work? Let's say I have Checker that checks for the penalties every time the activity starts. If it finds a penalty/penalties, then it adds them all together for me and subtracts them from the appropriate stats.

For example:

```
// There are 3 main outcomes that are suffered for being damaged too much
// The reduction of parry (PRY), dodge (DOD), and damage & accuracy (AM)
// The deductions range from -2 to -5. 
// I could declare Enums for each type

PRY2 = (- 2)
DOD2 = (- 2)
AM2 = (- 2)

PRY2 would be put into the equation if la > 0.50 && la <= 0.75 || ra > 0.50 && ra <= 0.75
DOD2 would be put into the equation if la > 0.50 && la <= 0.75 || ra > 0.50 && ra <= 0.75 || ll > 0.50 && ll <= 0.75 || rl > 0.50 && rl <= 0.75
AM2 would be put into the equation if la > 0.50 && la <= 0.75 || ra > 0.50 && ra <= 0.75 || c > 0.50 && c <= 0.75

PRY3 = (- 3)
DOD3 = (- 3)
AM3 = (- 3)

PRY3 would be put into the equation if c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50 || la > 0.25 && la <= 0.50 || ra > 0.25 && ra <= 0.50 || 
DOD3 would be put into the equation if c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50 || la > 0.25 && la <= 0.50 || ra > 0.25 && ra <= 0.50 || ll > 0.25 && ll <= 0.50 || rl > 0.25 && rl <= 0.50 
AM3 would be put into the equation if c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50 || la > 0.25 && la <= 0.50 || ra > 0.25 && ra <= 0.50 || 

PRY4 = (- 4)
DOD4 = (- 4)
AM4 = (- 4)

PRY4 would be put into the equation if la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 || ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 || ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25 || rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25
DOD4 would be put into the equation if la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 || ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 || ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25 || rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25
AM4 would be put into the equation if la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 || ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 || ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25 || rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25

PRY5 = (- 5)
DOD5 = (- 5)
AM5 = (- 5)

PRY5 would be put into the equation if h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 || c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25 || la <= 0.0 || ra <= 0.0 || ll <= 0.0 || rl <= 0.0
DOD5 would be put into the equation if h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 || c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25 || la <= 0.0 || ra <= 0.0 || ll <= 0.0 || rl <= 0.0
AM5 would be put into the equation if h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 || c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25 || la <= 0.0 || ra <= 0.0 || ll <= 0.0 || rl <= 0.0

// I'm not sure how, but somehow it would know, since it's PRY, then it knows to take the Enum and deduct it from the PRY slot and not the DOD or AM slots. 
// Is this a step in the right direction?
```

Here's the code that I have currently (coding out every single permutation):

```
//      SETTING DATA
//      WEAPON 1
//      MELEE           
        try {
            float STRF = NumberUtils.toFloat(pref.getString("strength", ""), 0.0f);
            float MCF = NumberUtils.toFloat(pref.getString("melee", ""), 0.0f);
            float W1AttF = NumberUtils.toFloat(pref.getString("w1attack", ""), 0.0f);

    // ALL LIMBS > 0.00 && h <= 0.25
            if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 && c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 26));
            } 
        // HEAD h > 0.25 && h <= 0.50   
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.25 && h <= 0.50 && c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 21));
            }
            // HEAD h > 0.50 && h <= 0.75   
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.50 && h <= 0.75 && c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 21));
            }
            // HEAD h > 0.75    
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.75  && c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 21));
            }
        // CHEST c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 && c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 26));
            } 
            // CHEST c > 0.50 && c <= 0.75
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 && c > 0.50 && c <= 0.75
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 26));
            } 
            // CHEST c > 0.75
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25 && c > 0.75
                    && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25
                    && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 26));
            } 
        // HEAD ONLY    
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h > 0.0 && h <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 5));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && h <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            } 
        // CHEST ONLY   
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && c > 0.0 && c <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 5));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && c > 0.25 && c <= 0.50) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 3)); 
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && c > 0.50 && c <= 0.75) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 2));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && c <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            } 
        // LEFT ARM ONLY    
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && la > 0.0 && la <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 4));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && la > 0.25 && la <= 0.50) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 3)); 
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && la > 0.50 && la <= 0.75) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 2));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && la <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            } 
        // RIGHT ARM ONLY   
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ra > 0.0 && ra <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 4));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ra > 0.25 && ra <= 0.50) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 3)); 
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ra > 0.50 && ra <= 0.75) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 2));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ra <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            }   
        // LEFT LEG ONLY    
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ll > 0.0 && ll <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 4));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && ll <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            }   
        // RIGHT LEG ONLY   
            else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && rl > 0.0 && rl <= 0.25) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString((STRF + MCF + W1AttF) - 4));
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0 && rl <= 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("Dead");
            }   

            else if (W1AttF == 0.0 || MCF == 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText("");
            } else if (MCF != 0.0 && W1AttF != 0.0) {
                weapon1attack.setText(Float.toString(STRF + MCF + W1AttF));
            }   
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {}
```

Comment: The number of permutations is **15625** (5^6), **not 7776** (6^5).

Comment: *Each permutation will likely result in a different output.* -- But *what* is the expected output for each case?

Comment: I don't think you've any choice if you want 5^6 outcomes, but one way to slightly simplify this in terms of reading at least will be to categorise the 'health'; rather than "(h > 0 && h <= 0.25)", make an enum and work out those values first, so it reduces to "(h == Health.LowHealth)", etc.

Comment: The crucial question is: What should happen for each permutation/combination? It seems that in most cases, the result should simply be `weapon1attack.setText("Dead");`. You could probably just define the rules for the cases where the result is **not** `Dead`, and let `Dead` be the default case. As Danil pointed out in his answer, something like this could be written compactly in a `switch`, but the question about how you are going to define these 15625 cases remains open. You certainly do not want do define them manually, but maybe based on some rules...?

Comment: If there's no sane way of *computing* the result, I would recommend creating a lookup table `float[][][][][] LUT = { ... }`, convert the value to an index according to the 25/50/75/... rules and do `result = LUT[i1][i2][i3][i4][i5][i6];` Still, I suspect that one would run into Java source file size limitations if one tries to tabulate that many values. Besides, there's no way the OP would do this manually. In one way or another the table would have to be generated, in which case the generation code can just as well be put directly in place of the table.

Comment: Set something to be `STRF + MCF + W1AttF`, and give it a meaningful name.  Suppose that someone went through and deleted every occurrence of `weapon1attack.setText(String)`.  How would you find what should go where?  Convert that logic into code, and this problem will be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

There's too little to go on what the *desired* result for each case looks like to go on. From the comments in the code I gather its some kind of RPG damage calculation.

It might be best to describe the problem in natural language first, or rather not the *problem*, but the *rules* governing the outcome of each combination of parameters. Looking at the patterns that emerge from the rules, its usually possible the define a reasonably small set of cases that can be expressed as mathematical formulas.

If you really want to have absolutely free control of the outcome of each case, you would need to enumerate the cases, and build a data structure containing the outcome for each possible case (e.g. a *data file* listing the outcome for each combination that is read into memory in some form).

Speculating on what I see in your code, I presume you are trying to figure out damage depending on location, weapon, defense etc.

This lends itself well to using simple mathematical formulas, e.g. first determine the *location*, and depending on that assign a dmanage modifier (pseudocode):

```
 modifier = 1.0; // defaults to "normal" damager
 switch (location) {
     case HEAD:
         modfier *= 2.00; // double damage
     case CHEST:
         modifier *= 0.75; // 75% damage
     default:
         // elsewhere: no change
         break;
 }
 // ... further modify based on other parameters like attack
 // type, defense type whatever you have

 // now figure out a base damage, purely fictional
 baseDmg = attack - defense;
 // we don't want negative damage in case def > att,
 // so if negative set to 1.0
 baseDmg = Math.max(baseDmg, 1.0);

 // caluclate final dmg using modifier
 realDmg = baseDmg * modifier;

 if (realDmg > life)
     // dead!
 else 
     // ouch!
```

Try to break your rules down so you can write it like the example above.

Comment: I agree. you have to break down your problem to little problems first.

Comment: I think I broke it down successfully. See the OP for EDITS

Comment: @Mikitz I see, my initial guess wasn't too far off. First I would treat each limb separately, at best you could model them as objects (so penalty calculation can work with multiple limbs, e.g. one method for left *and* right arm). Cross limb dependencies can be modeled in various ways, it depends on the actual rules. You could either assign a modifier calculated over all other limbs, or just limit stats depending on the state of another limb (e.g. arm.dodge = min(arm.dodge, head.dodge)). I can't think of any reasonable (understandable for player) rule set that couldn't be broken down this way.

Comment: would mind expanding on that? I'm not really sure how I'd go about it. This doesn't need to be understood by the player, it just has to function within the app as it is in the OP.

Comment: @Mikitz06 Expand on what? Nobody can do more than outline possibilities when the requirements are pretty vague. And as far as "understood by the player" goes, I wasn't talking about the *code* but the *concept* that is modeled by the code - if your game behaves incomprehensibly, the player will just drop it.

Comment: I just don't think what you wrote out in code is applicable (because the penalties don't function as your wrote), so I asked for you to clarify (with code maybe?) what you mean in the comment before your last. If it helps, this is a companion app for a tabletop RPG, not an RPG being developed for Android. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Mikitz06 You ask me to *expand* (and again totally without specifing on *what*) because something in my example doesn't match *your* rules, which you never *stated*? Sorry, thats not how it works. I don't play guesswork games because someone neglects to include problem details. And I don't write an essay on how to model RPG's in code either. Its no shame to ask "I dont understand what you mean with/how to apply (sentence, statement, paragraph)". But "please expand [missing parameter]" *is just lazy*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that converts your parameters to unique integer from 0 to 15625 (5^6) corresponding to your permutation, and then branch according to it.

Edit:
Another option may be to move this rules to a config file and process it in Java code.

Comment: That would still leave him coding each branch separately.

Comment: He will be able to merge the branches with similar operations using comparison operators on integer codes.

Comment: In reply to the comment in the OP. Creating an enumeration is better, it is a more structural approach. But I can hardly imagine how you can create an enumeration with 15625 distinct values in Java. Using integers is something like enumeration from C language.

Comment: I don't think it'd be that much actually. Some will be the same as shown in the OP. I'd have to Enum the results and not the health values (IE `h > 0.00 && h <= 0.25`) as the health values depend on percentages and could not be predicted. But, the results could potentially be turned into Enums. Then again, although it might not be 15,625, it'd still be an outrageously large number.

Comment: second thought, I don't think so. See the OP, I think I've had a breakthrough thought :)